# Can I set the default activity to an activity from a module that isn't the base module?

Tags: android-studio, module

I made an instant dynamic feature module containing an activity that I want to be the default launch activity.

The solution form here gives me the error "No Default activity": 
[How change default on launch module in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331849/how-change-default-on-launch-module-in-android-studio)

Comment: Have you tried defining activity of instant DFM in manifest file as a launcher with it's "complete package name"? Because I had done the same months ago and was working perfectly for me.

Comment: Doing so from the DFM manifest file gives me the error "Default Activity not found". My application extends SplitCompatApplication, did yours?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60836123/6911538

Comment: Is the syntax of step 2 literal? If so then please explain it because I haven't seen it before.